# Regular Expression on keypress for decimals with negative values

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi can someone help me to improve this regular expression on this function to include negative values?

the function is:

```
function Validate7EntY2Dec(e, field) {
    key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which
    // backspace
    if (key == 8) return true

    // 0-9 a partir del .decimal  
    if (field.value != "") {
        if ((field.value.indexOf(".")) > 0) {
            if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
                if (field.value == "") return true
                regexp = /[0-9]{2}$/
                return !(regexp.test(field.value))
            }
        }
    }
    // 0-9 
    if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
        if (field.value == "") return true
        regexp = /[0-9]{7}/
        return !(regexp.test(field.value))
    }
    // .
    if (key == 46) {
        if (field.value == "") return false
        regexp = /^[0-9]+$/
        return regexp.test(field.value)
    }
    // other key
    return false
}
```

as far as I get `/[0-9]{2}$/` validates two digits after the decimal point, and `/[0-9]{7}/` validates seven digist in the integer. I would like to this accept also negative values so the user can insert `-1234567.12` for example.

I found this regex `^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$` on other question but dont know how to insert in my function. 
Also found that adding a `-` on `/[0-9]{7}/` will accept negative values but it didnt, i did this: `/[-0-9]{7}/`

I need to keep my function because its been used already.

thank you in advance!

edit:

After the recommendation of @Ian my code was like this:

```
function Validate7EntY2Dec_Neg(e, field) {
    key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which
    // backspace
    if (key == 8) return true

    // 0-9 a partir del .decimal  
    if (field.value != "") {
        if ((field.value.indexOf(".")) > 0) {
            if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
                if (field.value == "") return true
                regexp = /[0-9]{2}$/
                return !(regexp.test(field.value))
            }
        }
    }
    // 0-9 
    if (key > 47 && key < 58) {
        if (field.value == "") return true
        regexp = /[0-9]{7}/
        return !(regexp.test(field.value))
    }
    // .
    if (key == 46) {
        if (field.value == "") return false
        regexp = /^[+-]?[0-9]{7}\.[0-9]{2}$/
        return regexp.test(field.value)
    }
    // other key
    return false
}
```

The change is on "function if (key == 46)..."

```
if (key == 46) {
   if (field.value == "") return false
   regexp = /^[+-]?[0-9]{7}\.[0-9]{2}$/
   return regexp.test(field.value)
}
```

@Ian how to escape - ??

Comment: Why use regex though? `number < 0` is a perfectly fine check for negative values

Comment: the regex is for the decimal @SeinopSys , I need 7 integers and 2 decimals maximum

Comment: You could use different ways to validate those parts too, and it'd be easier to maintain than a regular expression based solution.

Comment: Yes I know that I can use different ways to validate that but I'm now running on regular expressions.... I have maybe +150 attached to that function and I can't change them all.. that's why changing the function solves my problem :))) but thank you for the obvious alternative answer lol

Comment: Your comment says _"I need 7 integers and 2 decimals **maximum**_ but your regex `/[0-9]{7}/` says that you want ***exactly*** 7 digits and `/[0-9]{2}$/` ***exactly*** 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer Stephen P. Must be something wrong because that exactly regex allows me to insert "-1234.1" if I want. The problem now is other thing more than that but thank you anyway :)))

Comment: Sorry, yes, I missed that it is returning `!(regexp.test(field.value))` ... return true _until_ it matches 7-digits.

Answer (score 0):

^[+-]?[0-9]{7}\.[0-9]{2}$ should work. The caret forces start of string and the dollar the end. I have also forced a 7.2 digit number, I assume that is what you want. Also there is the optional +/- to start with.

Comment: yeap, I want that kind of regex but IN my function.... can help me to include +/- on the existing Validate7EntY2Dec function? thanks :)))

Comment: Use the regex I showed you. The line regexp = /^[0-9]+$/ should contain mine to validate the whole number. Break it up if you want to validate  the integer and decimal places separately

Comment: cool, thanks, i will try it right now, we are approaching to my aiming result. how can i break it up to validate integer and decimal places separately?

Comment: it didnt worked. it doesnt allow "-" and "." for decimal either :/

Comment: What kind of regex are you using? You probably need to escape the -. Not sure why the . causes problems, depends on the type of regex.

Comment: Also to split the regex lose the bit before the \. for the decimal and after for the integer

Comment: please take a look at my answer. thank you for your interest on this! I'll need some sort of code because I can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Apparently javascript sees a \  as a proper character so you need to escape it as well so you need \\.

Comment: Just seen your message.  The first bit in my regex will work escaping the -. The second bit should work too. Escape the hyphen and double escape  the dot

Comment: ok, im not spliting the regex, take a look how I am using it and where I am using it, it is okey? also, can you please write the regex or the code (would be better) with the escapes you mention?? for example I cant get what hyphen do you mean.

Comment: Looking good so far.  As I said you need to use two backslashes to escape characters. The plus, minus and dot will need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you stop worrying about keypresses and validate the whole field each time it's changed. I believe this wouldn't cause any performance problem and would vastly improve your code's maintainability.

I would then propose the following code :

```
function Validate7EntY2Dec_Neg(e, field) {
    return /^[+-]?[0-9]{7}\.[0-9]{2}$/.test(field.value);
}
```